# How can I toggle whether music plays from within a popover view in iOS?

Tags: ios

I have a button that allows the user to toggle whether the app plays music or not. When the button is toggled, the code modifies the value of a key in `NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults()` to indicate the new state of the switch.

The obvious solution would to to check the value of the key when the view appears (in `viewDidAppear`, for instance), and play music if the key indicates to do so. However, the music setting is toggled from within a popover view, so the music needs to be able to be turned on or off after the underling view (the view the popover view appears over) has already appeared.

In other words, I need music in a view that has already appeared to turn on or off whenever the associated value in `NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults()` changes.

Comment: Have you tried using NSNotificationCenter to call a method when you change the play/pause states?  https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSNotificationCenter_Class/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use [Key-Value Observing](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/BuildingCocoaApps/AdoptingCocoaDesignPatterns.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014216-CH7-XID_8) to do something whenever the key in the user defaults changes. However, KVO is a sometimes little bit messy to implement and some people dislike it.

An alternative might be to make a delegate protocol and make the view controller presenting the popover the delegate of the whatever controller responds to toggling the switch in the popover view. This way, you can notify view controller presenting the popover whenever the user toggles the switch in the popover.